# Give Android apps permission to access files

Tags: android, git, ssh

Is there any way to give Android apps permission to access hidden or other files? I am trying to use Sgit to do stuff with Git, but I need some SSH keys. I put some keys in the `.ssh` folder inside the "root" folder (I think), `/storage/sdcard0/`, but I couldn't access that `.ssh` folder with SGit, or any other folders starting with a dot for that matter, or anything outside the `/storage/sdcard0` folder either (there is no "up a folder" command). I know I could just put them in some other folder, but I feel like putting them in .ssh might make them safer somehow.

Am I not able to access the ".something" folders from SGit because of SGit, or is my phone not giving it permission, or what? SGit is also not getting access to folders outside `/storage/sdcard0/`. Is that the same thing or something different? If it is the phone, is there a way to grant SGit or other apps access? I would like to be able to do this without rooting, but if I have to root I probably will.

Comment: To modify files outside of storage, you need to have root access.

Comment: So why can other apps access it? For example, I also use an app called File Manager, and it can go out of that folder just fine.